# understanding when to use the binomial theorem.. or using it properly in different questions

Tags: binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

So I have a problem that says:

A fair coin is tossed repeatedly. $Y$ is the number of the toss on which the 3rd $H$ appears.

find $P(Y=4)$

When I approached this problem I thought I'd try the binomial theorem and used $p = .5$ and $X = 4$ and $n = 3$. but when I looked at the answer i do get $\left(\begin{array}{c}3\\2\end{array}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^4$, but no $(1-p)^{n-x}$ like I the binomial distribution formula said. The answers also showed the same type of solution for $Y = 5, 6, 7,$ etc.

so why is the $(1-p)^{n-x}$ part taken off?

Comment: Am I the only one or there is someone else too who thinks the ans is somewhat fishy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the third head on the fourth toss, one of the following sequences of tosses must occur: HHTH, HTHH, THHH. It's now clear that the probability is $3/16$.

In general, don't forget the $Y$-th toss must be a head.

Comment: so could I say in general, if i want to find the p(x) where a coin is tossed n times and X is the number of Hs, THEN i could use the PMF of the binomial theorem, but if its asking for p(x) where you get H on the nth toss, then you have to figure it out manually by adding the probability of each event...?

Comment: Given that the last toss (the Y-th toss) is the third head, the other two heads must come from the previous Y-1 tosses. Thus, your probability for $Y=4$ is (3 choose 2) $(1/2)^4$.

Comment: so would you say the (3 choose 2) is from [(the nth success) choose (given 2 successes)] ?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, when tossing a (not necessarily fair) coin,  the $k$'th Heads occurs on the $n$'th toss when there are exactly $k-1$ Heads in the first $n-1$ tosses and then the $n$'th toss is Heads.  Thus if tosses are independent, each with probability $p$ of Heads, the probability is ${n-1 \choose k-1} p^k q^{n-1-k}$.